# showing different versions of django for same environment in cmd prompt and vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, cmd

I use command  `py -m django --version` in cmd prompt it returns **3.2** as my django version
but when i use the same command in vscode it returns **3.1.9**. why is that

Comment: Just clarifying, you are not using a virtual environment in your cmd prompt, correct?

Comment: i am using virtual environment

Comment: You will have to activate the virtual environment inside the vscode cmd as well if you want  `py -m django --version` to read the same version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see which version is configured in each:

- command prompt is defined by "path" in environmental variables
- VScode is configured using GUI from the bottom left corner of the app where it shows the interpreter being used.